# Pass payload from React Native to Android Fragment

Tags: android, react-native

I have a fragment where I'd need to get the payload from React Native component. The CodeRNFragment under create is starting a new Activity which is a React Activity to invoke the RN component in the following way:

```
public class CodeRNFragment extends BaseView {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MyFirstReactActivity.class );
    startActivity(i);
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setupViews();
  }
  
  private void setupViews() {
    payload = ActivityStarterModule.getPayload();
    if (payload != null){
        System.out.println("payload content: "+ payload);
        viewModel.onCodeConfirmed();
    }
  }
}
```

The above CodeRNFragment is invoking MyFirstReactActivity to launch the RN component:

```
public class MyFirstReactActivity extends ReactActivity  implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String activityName = i.getStringExtra("activityName");

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(getApplication()).getPackages();
        packages.add(new ActivityStarterReactPackage());
        
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setJavaScriptExecutorFactory(new HermesExecutorFactory())
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackages(packages)
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();
        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "ReactNativeProject");

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ReactNativeProject";
    }
}
```

Then, the ScanCode is ran to obtain the details of a code which would be sent back to Android Fragment:

```
const ScanCode = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = useState(true);
  const [jsonInfo, setJSONInfo] = useState("");
  
  const parseCode = (data: string) => {
    const matches = data.matchAll(rgx);
    const payload: payload = {
      name: "",
      customerID: "",
    };
    for (const match of matches) {
      payload.name = match[1];
      payload.customerID = match[3];
    }
    setJSONInfo(JSON.stringify(payload));
    
    if (payload.customerID) {
      NativeModules.ActivityStarter.setPayload(jsonInfo);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        {code && (
          <Text>Scan Code</Text>
        )}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        {code && (
          <Component
            onRead={(event: {
              nativeEvent: { value: string };
            }) => {
              parseCode(event.nativeEvent.value);
              setCode(false);
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I have this ActivityStarterModule which extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule to have a ReactMethod and set the value in a local variable to save the payload:

```
public class ActivityStarterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private static String payload;

    public static String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    ActivityStarterModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ActivityStarter";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void payload(String params) {
        setPayload(params);
    }

}
```

However, I am getting null value in payload because of this error:

```
TypeError: _reactNative.NativeModules.ActivityStarter.setPayload is not a 
function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
```

How could I set the value of payload from React Native component and pass to other fragments?

Thanks in advance